# Error in R: 'Object not found', code not working in R Markdown

Tags: r

I have a peculiar situation where a chunk of code is working for me when I run it in the console, but when I try to knit it in an R Markdown file, I am getting an error. Here is the code:

```
    {r,echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.width=3, fig.height=3}
    library(cdcfluview)
    library(mosaic)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)

    neflu <- get_flu_data("census", "1", "ilinet", years=1997:2016)
    neflu[neflu=="X"]<-NA

    wk_new <- rep(NA, nrow(neflu))
    season_new <- rep('0', nrow(neflu))

    for(i in 1:nrow(neflu)){
     if(neflu$WEEK[i] == 40){
      wk_num <- 1
     }
    wk_new[i] <- wk_num
    wk_num <- wk_num+1

    if(neflu$WEEK[i] < 40) {
       season_new[i] <- paste(neflu$YEAR[i]-1, '-', neflu$YEAR[i])
     } else {
      season_new[i] <- paste(neflu$YEAR[i], '-', neflu$YEAR[i]+1)
     }
  }

  neflu_new <- cbind(neflu, wk_new, season_new)


  neflu_agg <- neflu_new %>%
  mutate(weighted_ili = as.numeric(X..WEIGHTED.ILI))%>%
  group_by(REGION.TYPE, season_new) %>%
  summarize(peak_ili = max(weighted_ili, na.rm=TRUE),
        cum_ili = sum(weighted_ili,na.rm=TRUE),
        peak_wk = wk_new[which.max(weighted_ili)])

  neflu_agg2 <- subset(neflu_agg, peak_wk != 5, select=c(REGION.TYPE,season_new,peak_ili,cum_ili, peak_wk))

  plot(peak_wk, peak_ili, main= "Peak ILI vs Peak Week", xlab= "Peak Week", ylab= "Peak ILI")
  nelm1 <- lm(peak_ili~1+peak_wk)
  abline(nelm1, col='red')
  plot(peak_ili, cum_ili, main= "Cumulative ILI vs Peak ILI", xlab= "Peak ILI", ylab= "Cumulative ILI")
  nelm2 <- lm(cum_ili~1+peak_ili)
  abline(nelm2, col='blue')
```

And here is the error message I am getting:

```
   The object peak_wk not found Calls:<Anonymous> . . . 
   WithCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> plot execution halted".
```

I have tried changing the code this this, but am still getting errors:

```
    {r,echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.width=3, fig.height=3}
    library(cdcfluview)
    library(mosaic)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)

    neflu <- get_flu_data("census", "1", "ilinet", years=1997:2016)
    neflu[neflu=="X"]<-NA

    wk_new <- rep(NA, nrow(neflu))
    season_new <- rep('0', nrow(neflu))

    for(i in 1:nrow(neflu)){
     if(neflu$WEEK[i] == 40){
      wk_num <- 1
     }
    wk_new[i] <- wk_num
    wk_num <- wk_num+1

    if(neflu$WEEK[i] < 40) {
       season_new[i] <- paste(neflu$YEAR[i]-1, '-', neflu$YEAR[i])
     } else {
      season_new[i] <- paste(neflu$YEAR[i], '-', neflu$YEAR[i]+1)
     }
  }

  neflu_new <- cbind(neflu, wk_new, season_new)

  weighted_ili <- mutate(neflu_new, weighted_ili = as.numeric(X..WEIGHTED.ILI))
  peak_ili <- max(weighted_ili, na.rm=TRUE)
  cum_ili <- sum(weighted_ili,na.rm=TRUE)
  peak_wk <- wk_new[which.max(weighted_ili)]

  neflu_agg <- neflu_new %>%
  mutate(weighted_ili = as.numeric(X..WEIGHTED.ILI))%>%
  group_by(REGION.TYPE, season_new) %>%
  summarize(peak_ili = max(weighted_ili, na.rm=TRUE),
        cum_ili = sum(weighted_ili,na.rm=TRUE),
        peak_wk = wk_new[which.max(weighted_ili)])

  neflu_agg2 <- subset(neflu_agg, peak_wk != 5, select=c(REGION.TYPE,season_new,peak_ili,cum_ili, peak_wk))

  plot(peak_wk, peak_ili, main= "Peak ILI vs Peak Week", xlab= "Peak Week", ylab= "Peak ILI")
  nelm1 <- lm(peak_ili~1+peak_wk)
  abline(nelm1, col='red')
  plot(peak_ili, cum_ili, main= "Cumulative ILI vs Peak ILI", xlab= "Peak ILI", ylab= "Cumulative ILI")
  nelm2 <- lm(cum_ili~1+peak_ili)
  abline(nelm2, col='blue')
```

Here is the error I get now:

```
    Error in FUN(X[[i]],...): only defined on data frame with all 
    numeric variables Calls:
```

Any help with just getting this code to knit would be greatly appreciated. I am sure I am just missing something very obvious but I can't figure it out.

Comment: In your first block of code, you may need to reference peak_wk as neflu_agg$peak_wk. It is my understanding that `dplyr` returns a data.frame. Your code that references peak_wk seems to be feeding a data.frame named neflu_agg.

Comment: Do you mean I should do that in the summarize portion of the code? So neflu_agg$peak_wk=wk_new[which.max(weighted_ili)]) ?

If so, I get a new error message, saying there is an unexpected '=' in cum_ili = sum(weighted_ili,na.rm=TRUE),

Comment: No, I am referring to the non-`dplyr` code such as the `plot` function. Note the error message: `plot execution halted`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. So I did that for each peak_wk in the 'plot' portion of the code. I also assumed I would have to do it for peak_ili and cum_ili as well, but still getting an error. Now the error is saying that peak_ili is not found in calls... Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: My best guess is that there is a naming issue somewhere. Make sure that all of the names line up correctly (spelling and upper/lower case). If all that is good, look at `str(neflu_agg)` or `str(neflu_agg)`, whichever you are plotting,  to make sure the variables are there.

Comment: I figured it out, I posted an answer. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Sure thing. Just be careful using `attach`. It is often safer to use `with`. A second possible solution would be to try the data argument in plot. I think the following is equivalent: `plot(peak_ili~peak_wk, neflu_agg2, data= main= "Peak ILI vs Peak Week", xlab= "Peak Week", ylab= "Peak ILI")`. Note that X and Y are reversed relative to the typical `plot` function.

Answer (score 1):

I now realize why I was getting the error, with help from lmo:

peak_wk, peak_ili, and cum_ili were not defined in the global environment. I had to specify where the plot() function was pulling the data from:

```
    attach(neflu_agg2)
```

This worked just fine.